# Separate processes, each run in multithread JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading, process, scheduled-tasks

I have 4 separate processes which need to go one after another.

1st process 
2nd process
3rd process
4th process

Since, every process is connected to one another, each process should run after process before him finishes.

Each process has its own variable length which will be various as programs data input grows.

But some sketch would be like this

Program Runs

1st process - lasts 10 seconds

2nd process - has 300 HTTP get requests, last 3 minutes

3rd process - has 600 HTTP get requests, lasts 6 minutes

4th process - lasts 1 minute

Program is written in java

Thanks for any answer!

Comment: If the processes are sequential, why not simply implement it in a way that each process that finishes calls the next one ?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a shell script/batch file.

Comment: @alfasin OMG no! Talk about Major Coupling if you do that route!

Comment: @SnakeDoc a) you're misusing the term `coupling` (see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)) and b) he specifically noted that "each process should run after process before him finishes"

Comment: @alfasin its a good idea BUT, won't it be even better if there is a wrapper which calls 1st process and once it is complete call the 2nd process and so on ?

Comment: @alfasin I don't believe I am misusing `coupling` since your suggesting would make every process/method dependent-on/tied-to/coupled-to the previous. This is bad. Instead, he should implement some sort of "manager" class/method that executes the others in the proper order, maintaining control of the logic flow from a central spot.

Comment: @Ankit it won't be "better" it's another options that requires a different design which is more complex (each process that finishes will have to raise a flag which will have to be checked periodically etc) and not necessarily better. I like to makes things as simple as possible ;)

Comment: @alfasin the OP probably doesn't need to check if the process is complete or not... it will return to the calling method after it's done. No need to implement threads here, it's a sequential logic. This runs, then this, then that, etc.

Comment: I agree with @SnakeDoc. These are 4 different processes and we do not necessarily need to make changes in them to call the next process. We can simply write a wrapper over it to call it one after the other. The wrapper can be a shell script or a java code. Your thoughts?

Comment: @Ankit and SnakeDoc - I'm glad that you're both in agreement, only that: a) the OP tagged the question as multithreading which means that every process can/might be such, and b) he specifically said that every process should run only AFTER the previous one is completed. And snake: the *idea* behind coupling is that when two classes are coupled - if you change one there is a good chance that you'll have to make changes in the other - this is not the case when you call from one process to the next, at least not more than doing the same using a wrapper!

Comment: The notion of having one method/process invoke another which invokes another which invokes another makes it impossible to execute just 1 process/method as stand-alone... making them tightly-coupled methods/processes (program logic and/or data flows between them). Basically each method/process/module is dependent on the others execution, which violates OOP principals. Instead, it's much better to have a wrapper/manager class which controls when each will be invoked, be it simple procedural flow or is locks/checks must be done. Shortcuts are always the longest distance between two points.  ;-P

Comment: @SnakeDoc that's true as long as the process don't DEPEND on each other's execution - which is kind of what he said...

Answer (score 2):

There is no concurrency support in the java API for your use case because what you're asking for is the opposite of concurrent. You have a set of four mutually dependent operations that need to be run in a specific order. You only need, and should probably only use, one thread to correctly handle this case.

It would be reasonable and prudent to put each operation in its own method or class, based on how complex the operations are.

If you insist on using multiple threads, your main thread should maintain a list of runnables. Iterate through the list. Pop the first runnable from the list, create a new thread for that runnable, start the thread, and then invoke join() on the thread. The main thread will block until the runnable is complete. The loop will take you through all the runnables in order. Again, there is no good reason to do this. There may or may not be a bad reason.